# How i can add text in title and body in google slide?

Tags: php, google-slides-api

I need to add a title and description via php in google slide

I create slide

```
    $requests = array();
    $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Slides_Request(
        array(
            'createSlide' => array (
            'objectId' => $nameSlide,
            'insertionIndex' => 0,
            'slideLayoutReference' => array (
                'predefinedLayout' => 'TITLE_AND_BODY'
            )   
        )
    ));

    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Slides_BatchUpdatePresentationRequest(array(
        'requests' => $requests
    ));
    $response = self::$serviceSlide->presentations->batchUpdate($id, $batchUpdateRequest);
    $createSlideResponse = $response->getReplies()[0]->getCreateSlide();
    $id = $createSlideResponse->getObjectId();
```

The slide has this format

[image]

How can I add text to the title and description?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation specifically in [Editing and Styling Text](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/styling) section.

> This page tells you how to edit and style text in your presentation
>   using the Slides API.

Follow the sample code provided [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/styling#inserting_deleting_or_replacing_text).